# How to debug mobile specific movement events (beta, gamma, alpha)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the code of particles.js and came across the following lines of code:

```
if (orientationSupport && !desktop) {
          // Map tiltX range [-30,30] to range [0,winW]
          var ratioX = (winW - 0) / (30 - -30);
          pointerX = (tiltX - -30) * ratioX + 0;
          // Map tiltY range [-30,30] to range [0,winH]
          var ratioY = (winH - 0) / (30 - -30);
          pointerY = (tiltY - -30) * ratioY + 0;
        } else {
          pointerX = mouseX;
          pointerY = mouseY;
        }
```

The above lines of code can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground/blob/master/jquery.particleground.js#L86)**.

Now this particular plugin uses these mobile specific events only for a tiny parallax.js, but I've seen plugins that use code similar to the above for really high tech parallax simulation.

Now my question is, because obviously these can't be tested on a destop PC, how do you test such code at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

- Have a webserver which you and your mobile can connect to. If some JS doesn't work, check the console on your PC, it will mostly tell you every error you did.
- [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240748/4796321): use the [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) on google chrome
- [@choz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240517/4796321): if you only need rotation you can just go into the dev-mode in google chrome [F12]

For other questions, it's worth to take a look at the [device orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation).

Comment: yeah ! i'am not sure a mobile has a console or how good its gonna be if it has one at all ! Thanks though ! i'll try it .

Comment: A mobile does not have a console, so you have to blindly test it there and if something doesn't work, you have to inspect it on your pc.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug mobile Chrome with Chrome console on PC. Here is link how to connect it: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score -1):

In chrome, you can use [`Toggle Device Mode`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + M`.

And taken from the doc, you are capable to:

- Test your responsive designs by emulating different screen sizes and
  resolutions, including Retina displays.
- Evaluate your site's performance using the network emulator, without
  affecting traffic to other tabs.
- Visualize and inspect CSS media queries.
- Accurately simulate device input for touch events, geolocation, and device orientation.
- Enhance your current debugging workflow by combining device mode with the existing DevTools.

Edit:

You can change to various orientation mode according to your needs.

[image: chromeDevMode]

Comment: Can this mode change the rotation of the device? Hint: No.

Comment: @timmyRS **Yes**, you can change the device orientation.

Comment: Since when? I'm working with chrome dev.-mode so often O.o

Comment: @timmyRS Since version [32](http://www.realeyes.com/blog/2014/02/19/a-quick-guide-to-chromes-new-built-in-device-emulation/)

Comment: @timmyRS You don't even read the 4th point or try to use dev tools before confirming. Will add screenshot to confirm this.